# как в JetPack Compose обратиться к элементу?

Tags: android-studio, android-jetpack-compose

У меня есть отрисовка pager-а. Хочу скрыть его по клику и столкнулся с тем, что не знаю, как к нему обратиться. Надеюсь на вашу помощь)

Comment: Никак. Тут используется другой подход - все следят за стейтом. Вы меняете стейт по клику - и все реагируют на изменение стейта.